# How to shift a range down one row based upon adjacent cell value using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to move the adjacent cell range `D:E` down one row based upon the value in column `B`.

For example, if a row in column `B` contains the word "Deposit", then the macro should shift the adjacent cell range `D:E` down one row.

My issue is that the macro is inserting two rows instead of just one.

I've included some screenshots of my data.

Here is my code:

```
Sub InsertCellsDown()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim cba As Range
    LastRow = Cells.Find("Deposit", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cba In Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
        If cba <> cba.Offset(1, 0) Then
            Range("D" & cba.Row & ":E" & cba.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    Next cba
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Starting data:**

[image: Starting data]

**Goal:**

[image: Goal]

**Problem:**

[image: Problem]

Comment: a common problem when inserting rows. Start the loop from the bottom of the range instead of the top.